# multiply each value that I get from 'for' statement in php

Tags: php

following is the steps in which i want to do things:

1. assign a value 1 to $x variable
2. using for loop increment this value upto 7, so that output is : 1234567
3. now multiply each value with 7, so that output is : 7 14 21 28 35 42 49.

for this i made the following code, but it does not work.

```
$yy=1;
for($yy==1; $yy<=8; $yy++){
$yy*7;

}echo $yy;
```

and i tried the do-while also :

```
$yy=1;
do{$yy*7;
echo $yy;}
while(
$yy>=7
)
```

but non is working. i think foreach will work here, not tried yet as i am not on it yet. will it be possible with any of these 2 functions?

Comment: There's a difference between == and =, you'll need to move the echo inside the loop and if you want to keep the result before echo-ing, you'll need to assing it to $yy. These seems like very basic questions, close to homework..

Comment: You would want to use a separate variable, $yy is the value you are looping through and you do not want to be changing it inside the loop beyond incrementing, or whatever action you want to put on it.
If you want to do addition you might want another variable such as $zz to do your addition / multiplication with.

Comment: Was this some kind of school home work. ?

Answer (score 3):

You just need for loops:

```
for($yy = 1; $yy <= 7; $yy++){
    echo $yy;
}
echo '<br/>';
for($yy = 1; $yy <= 7; $yy++){
    echo $yy*7 .' ';
}
```

The result will be like this

1234567 
7 14 21 28 35 42 49

You got wrong syntax: `$yy==1` (comparison operator) on your for looop, initialize `$yy=1` (assign operator) then the condition is `$yy<=7` not eight

Comment: @fiakfisk, i am new to programming, so pls spare me and give tips as much as possible..thanks

Comment: @user3450590 this topic is about control structure.. here in php manual it give samples http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php this is where a good explanation is found